# Under no circumstances do Politic methods work in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When calling a method:

```
$this->authorize('view', Role::class);
```

In the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Admin\Role\Controllers;

use App\Modules\Admin\Dashboard\Classes\Base;
use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RoleController extends Base
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('view', Role::class);

        $roles = Role::all();

        $this->title = "Title Role Index";

        $this->content = view('Admin::Role.index')->
        with([
            'roles' => $roles,
            'title' => $this->title,
        ])->render();

        return $this->renderOutput();
    }

    /**
     * Create of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Role $role)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Role $role)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Role $role)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Always get from browser:

```
403 | This action is unauthorized.
```

My Routes:

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'roles', 'middleware' => []], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'RoleController@index')->name('roles.index');
    Route::get('/create', 'RoleController@create')->name('roles.create');
    Route::post('/', 'RoleController@store')->name('roles.store');
    Route::get('/{role}', 'RoleController@show')->name('roles.read');
    Route::get('/edit/{role}', 'RoleController@edit')->name('roles.edit');
    Route::put('/{role}', 'RoleController@update')->name('roles.update');
    Route::delete('/{role}', 'RoleController@destroy')->name('roles.delete');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'permissions', 'middleware' => []], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PermissionsController@index')->name('permissions.index');
    Route::get('/create', 'PermissionsController@create')->name('permissions.create');
    Route::post('/', 'PermissionsController@store')->name('permissions.store');
    Route::get('/{role}', 'PermissionsController@show')->name('permissions.read');
    Route::get('/edit/{role}', 'PermissionsController@edit')->name('permissions.edit');
    Route::put('/{role}', 'PermissionsController@update')->name('permissions.update');
    Route::delete('/{role}', 'PermissionsController@destroy')->name('permissions.delete');
});
```

Politic:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Admin\Role\Policies;

use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role;
use App\Modules\Admin\Users\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class RolePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(): bool {
        // never run
        return true;
    }

    public function create(): bool {
        // never run
        return true;
    }

    public function update(): bool {
        // never run
        return true;
    }

    public function delete(): bool {
        // never run
        return true;
    }

    public function viewAny(): bool {
        // never run
        return true;
    }

    public function before() {
        // never run
        return true;
    }
}
```

File AuthServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role;
use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Policies\Role2Policy;
use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Policies\RolePolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Role::class => RolePolicy::class,
//        Role::class => Role2Policy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

File config/auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash'=>false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Modules\Admin\Users\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

File config/app.php:

```
<?php

use Facades\Menu;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'ru',
    'locales' => ['ru', 'en'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Faker Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This locale will be used by the Faker PHP library when generating fake
    | data for your database seeds. For example, this will be used to get
    | localized telephone numbers, street address information and more.
    |
    */

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        Lavary\Menu\ServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

        App\Services\Localization\LocalizationServiceProvider::class,

        App\Providers\ModularProvider::class,
        /*
         * modular provider
         */

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'Date' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Js' => Illuminate\Support\Js::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'RateLimiter' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        // 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Menu' => Lavary\Menu\Facade::class,
    ],

];
```

File .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2R0mEOI/CEYoRmqtxg9c/FUu1RJIXGU9hIUVFL21fYA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://crm.loc.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=crm
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

File Models Role:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models;

use App\Modules\Admin\Users\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'alias',
        'title',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function perms() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }


    public function savePermissions($perms) {
        if(!empty($perms)) {
            $this->perms()->sync($perms);
        }
        else {
            $this->perms()->detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me solve the problem.  I am new to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Add     **use AuthorizesRequests;** to your code

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Modules\Admin\Role\Controllers;
    
    use App\Modules\Admin\Dashboard\Classes\Base;
    use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests; // add this
    
    class RoleController extends Base
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests; // add this
    
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $this->authorize('view', Role::class);
    
            $roles = Role::all();
    
            $this->title = "Title Role Index";
    
            $this->content = view('Admin::Role.index')->
            with([
                'roles' => $roles,
                'title' => $this->title,
            ])->render();
    
            return $this->renderOutput();
        }
    
        /**
         * Create of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show(Role $role)
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit(Role $role)
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  \App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Role  $role
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy(Role $role)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```